# iOS Removing constraints progmatically issue

Tags: ios, constraints, xib, nslayoutconstraint

I have a xib for a TableViewCell and in this cell I have 4 labels stacked on top of each other. So imagine something like:

```
Label1
Label2
Label3
Label4
```

I added a constraint to the bottom of each of these labels to have 3 vertical space between them. Now, when you do this in the xib file, it also "creates" a constraint on the top of each of the other labels of 3. So basically it's like this:

Label1 I create a bottom constraint, so it also creates a top constraint on Label2 but they point to the same "Object". So on, and so on..

The problem is, at run time, depending on the data, I don't want to show some of these labels. For example I may only want 3 Labels so in that case I want to show Label1, Label2, and Label3. But I also don't want Label4 to take up any space because I don't want my Cell to be bigger than it has to be.

So I do something like this:

I wire the bottom constraint of label3 into my view controller and call it label3BottomConstraint, then do (as well as a bit more, but this is the important part):

```
label3BottomConstraint.constant = 0;
```

I do this and it works, but I see messages like this in the log:

```
  Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 

"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f913c1d0fc0 V:[UILabel:0x7f913e84d850'30%']-(3)-[UILabel:0x7f913e84e240'90% < 18']>"
```

So even though I set the bottom constraint to 0, the top constraint of label4 that was created by the xib file is still sticking around even though they are really the same NSLayoutConstraint Object. So how do I remove this one? And should I even worry about these messages?

**EDIT:** I've attempted to simplify it a bit by removing labels so I could describe it easier:

[image: my xib]

So in the middle I have a UIView centered horizontally around the two images, the mP and fP label, and the mLabel and fLabel. This UIView is called dataContainer.

dataContainer has top space 8, bottom space 8 and these are wired through the properties dataContainerBottomSpaceConstraint and dataContainerTopSpaceConstraint.

Both images have height 42, and bottom 2. These are wired through the properties {m/f}ImageHeightConstraint, and {m/f}ImageBottomConstraint.

Both mP and fP have height 17, and bottom 2, and for lack of a better word "inherit" top 2 from the images. These are wired through the properties {mP/fP}HeightConstraint, and {mP/fP}BottomConstraint.

Both mLabel1 and fLabel1 have height 15, bottom 3, and "inherit" top 2 from the mP/fP bottom 2. These properties are wired through {m/f}Line1BottomConstraint, and {m/f}Line1HeightConstraint.

At run time my goal right now is to remove the entire dataContainer so the most bottom thing showing on the cell is "x num". I can't just remove this subview because depending on the data it could show. So I do the following:

```
    cell.dataContainerBottomSpaceConstraint.constant = 0;
    cell.dataContainerTopSpaceConstraint.constant = 8;
    cell.dataContainer.hidden = YES;

    cell.mImageHeightConstraint.constant = 0;
    cell.fImageHeightConstraint.constant = 0;
    cell.mImageBottomConstraint.constant = 0;
    cell.fImageBottomConstraint.constant = 0;
    cell.mImage.hidden = YES;
    cell.flmage.hidden = YES;

    cell.mPBottomConstraint.constant = 0;
    cell.fPBottomConstraint.constant = 0;
    cell.mPHeightConstraint.constant = 0;
    cell.fPLabelHeightConstraint.constant = 0;
    cell.mPLabel.hidden = YES;
    cell.fPLabel.hidden = YES;

    cell.mLine1BottomConstraint.constant = 0;
    cell.fLine1BottomConstraint.constant = 0;
    cell.mLine1HeightConstraint.constant = 0;
    cell.fLine1HeightConstraint.constant = 0;
    cell.mLine1.hidden = YES;
    cell.fLine1.hidden = YES;
```

On the screen/simulator it looks exactly like what I want, but I see many of these messages in the logs:

```
        Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
  (
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7feddb8b3540 V:[UIImageView:0x7feddb8b3420(0)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fedd974a7a0 V:[UIImageView:0x7fedd974fd90(42)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7feddb9b2210 V:[UILabel:0x7feddb938360'mP'(17)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7feddb941250 V:[UILabel:0x7feddb9e81f0'mLabel1'(15)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7feddb954e50 V:[UILabel:0x7feddb94a180'fLabel1'(15)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7feddb91fff0 V:[UILabel:0x7feddb943cb0'fP'(17)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7feddb94cb10 V:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7feddb8b3420]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fedd9696640 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7feddb949900 V:[UIImageView:0x7feddb8b3420]-(2)-[UILabel:0x7feddb938360'mP']>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7feddb949b20 V:[UILabel:0x7feddb938360'mP']-(2)-[UILabel:0x7feddb9e81f0'mLabel1']>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7feddb949b70 V:[UILabel:0x7feddb9e81f0'mLabel1']-(3)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fedd9696640 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7feddb949c80 V:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7fedd974fd90]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fedd9696640 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7feddb949ea0 V:[UIImageView:0x7fedd974fd90]-(2)-[UILabel:0x7feddb943cb0'fP']>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7feddb949f60 V:[UILabel:0x7feddb94a180'fLabel1']-(3)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fedd9696640 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7feddb949fb0 V:[UILabel:0x7feddb943cb0'fP']-(2)-[UILabel:0x7feddb94a180'fLabel1']>"
     )

     Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
    NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fedd974a7a0 V:[UIImageView:0x7fedd974fd90(42)]
```

In this case it doesn't even seem like anything I'm doing is being picked up.

Comment: Can you give more details on the constraints you are setting? From the way you are describing, because you are doing the `label1.bottom - label2.top` spacing constraints, your `label3BottomConstraint` should be referencing `label4.top`. So from what you are describing, all that should be happening, is you are removing that 3 pt vertical space, but the label is still hanging around

Comment: @Killian I have added an edit showing more details.